# Посчитать количество дней между датами

Tags: php, sql

Из БД извлекаются несколько строк с календарными периодами.

Например:

```
1 строка )с 01.04.2012 по 10.04.2012
2 строка )с 11.04.2012 по 20.04.2012
3 строка )с 25.04.2012 по 30.04.2012
```

Нужно посчитать количество дней между конечной датой 1 строки и начальной датой 2 строки, конечной датой 2 строки и начальной датой 3 строки. И если не в одном промежутке дат кол-во дней не превышает 1-го, тогда сделать то-то.

Т.е. фактически проверить: существует ли разрыв дат между календарными периодами, либо они все числа идут подряд!

Comment: Поясню задачу, для объёмного восприятия!Администратор сайта создаёт категорию номера гостиницы, в которой устанавливает квоту для разрешения бронирования.Квот может быть несколько! Например:категория номера: Люксквота1 с 10-04-2012 по 15-04-2012 (т.е. бронь разрешается в этом периоде)квота2 с 16-04-2012 по 20-04-2012 (т.е. бронь разрешается в этом периоде)квота3 с 25-04-2012 по 30-04-2012 (т.е. бронь разрешается в этом периоде)Собственно между этими квотами может существовать разрыв дат(например: между квота2 и квота3), который говорит нам что бронирование запрещено в этом разрыве дат.

Answer (score 2):

Можно таким образом (PHP):

```
$now = time(); // текущее время (метка времени)
$your_date = strtotime("2017-01-01"); // какая-то дата в строке (1 января 2017 года)
$datediff = $now - $your_date; // получим разность дат (в секундах)

echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)); // вычислим количество дней из разности дат
```

> Почему количество секунд делим на `60 * 60 * 24`? Количество секунд
>   поделив на `60` получим количество минут (в одной минуте шестьдесят
>   секунд). Затем, поделив количество минут на `60` - получим количество
>   часов (в одном часе шестьдесят минут). А поделив количество часов на
>   `24` - получим количество дней (в одном дне двадцать четыре часа).

Пример взят отсюда: [Finding the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2040589/5275890)

Пример проверки нахождения даты между двумя датами: [PHP check if date between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070307/5275890)

Есть пример и на ruSO: [Разница между датами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451773/189339)

Для справки:

- [PHP time](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)
- [PHP strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)
- [PHP DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php)

Стоит отметить некоторые замечания:

> - [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) — преобразует текстовое представление даты на    английском языке в метку времени Unix.
> - Метка времени Unix — это количество секунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970    года 00:00:00 UTC.
> - [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) — возвращает временную метку в случае успеха, иначе возвращается `FALSE`. До версии PHP 5.1.0 в случае ошибки эта функция возвращала `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

На PHP:

```
print (strtotime ("11.04.2012")-strtotime ("10.04.2012"))/(60*60*24);
```

Пример был протестирован на PHP 5.2.13, на Denwer'е.

Comment: Это при условии что php 5.3 на серваке есть :)

Comment: Как это реализовать в цикле, чтобы вычиталась конечная дата квота1) - начальная дата квота2)

Comment: Если данные получены в индексный массив, например "$array", то:for ($i=1; $i<sizeof ($array)-1; $i+=2) print (strtotime ($array [$i+1])-strtotime ($array [$i]))/(60*60*24)."<br />";

Comment: в этом ответе производится деление на 86400, однако иногда в сутках бывает иное количество секунд

Comment: @Artem, вы о чем? `strtotime` существует с `php 4`.

Answer (score -1):

В БД Oracle это можно сделать примерно так (с аналитическими функциями, может наведет на мысли и в PHP)

```
with t(d1, d2) as
(
    select sysdate, sysdate+5 from dual
    union all
    select sysdate+8, sysdate+12 from dual
    union all
    select sysdate+25, sysdate+35 from dual
)
select 
    d1, -- Начало периода
    d2, -- Конец периода
    d2 - d1, -- Количество дней в периоде
    lead(d1) over (order by d1), -- Дата начала следующего периода
    lead(d1) over (order by d1) - d2 -- Количество "незанятых"  дней до начала след. периода
from t
```