# Разница между датами

Tags: php, время

Каким образом можно детально узнать разницу между двумя датами (сегодняшняя и некая, записанная в переменной) таким образом, чтобы результат был записан в 4 переменных: N лет, N месяцев, N часов, N минут? То есть, нужны именно 4 отдельных переменных для последующей работы с ними.

Comment: Надо перевести обе даты в UNIXTIME(), вычесть друг из друга. Полученное число - кол-во секунд между двумя датами. Далее в сети можно найти готовые функции, которые переводят занчение в секундах в нужные Вам 4 переменные

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Используйте ООП. [Документация DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php)

```
$now = new DateTime(); // текущее время на сервере
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i", '2014-09-12 23:59'); // задаем дату в любом формате
$interval = $now->diff($date); // получаем разницу в виде объекта DateInterval
echo $interval->y, "\n"; // кол-во лет
echo $interval->d, "\n"; // кол-во дней
echo $interval->h, "\n"; // кол-во часов
echo $interval->i, "\n"; // кол-во минут
```

`\n` добавлен только для удобства просмотра результатов, соответственно вместо `echo` присваиваем переменным или работаем напрямую со свойствами [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 3):

Мне пришлось писать функцию для себя, может кому понадобится:

```
function getPeriod($date1,$date2){
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    $y='';$m='';$d='';

    if ($interval->y>0) {
        if ($interval->y>4) 
            $y .=$interval->y . ' лет'; 
        else if ($interval->y == 1)
            $y .=$interval->y . ' год'; 
        else 
            $y .=$interval->y . ' года';
        $y .= ', ';
    }

    if ($interval->m>0) {
        if ($interval->m>4) 
            $m .= $interval->m . ' месяцев';
        else if ($interval->m>1)
            $m .= $interval->m . ' месяца';
        else 
            $m .= $interval->m . ' месяц';
        $m .= ', ';
    }

    if ($interval->d>0) {
        if ($interval->d>4) 
            $d .= $interval->d . ' дней';
        else if ($interval->d>1)
            $d .= $interval->d . ' дня';
        else 
            $d .= $interval->d . ' день';
    }

    return $y . $m . $d;
}
```

...

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2001-01-1');
$date2 = new DateTime('2012-12-4');

$period = getPeriod($date1,$date2);
```

Пример вывода:

```
11 лет, 11 месяцев, 1 день
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = strtotime([первая дата]);
$date2 = strtotime([вторая дата]);
$diff = ABS($date1 - $date2);
```

Дальше полученную `$diff` передать в функцию форматирования (например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago)